# Use the output "SMEMBERS" command as input to "MGET" in redis?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I am using [`redis-py`](https://pypi.org/project/redis/) (python redis library) in my code and would like to use the strings output by an `SMEMBERS` command directly in an `MGET` command.  I would like to do this *without* pulling all of the members into my python program, and then sending the `MGET` command using that data.  I'm not sure if `redis` (the actual database application itself) has any provisions for using output as input to another within itself, but I also a novice with it.

Is this something redis is capable of, a sort of internal piping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this something redis is capable of, a sort of internal piping?

Capable - yes, but not in a scalable manner. You can do that in a server-side Lua script but that would go against best practices and would yield unknown results in a clustered deployment.